# Is the heat kernel of a manifold $p$-integrable?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, heat-equation, semigroups-of-operators, integral-kernel

If $M$ is a separable, oriented Riemannian manifold, without any other assumption on its geometry, and $h$ is its heat kernel, it is known that $h(t,x,\cdot)$ is both *integrable*, and *square-integrable* for all $t>0$ and $x \in M$. Furthermore, it can be shown that $h(t,x,\cdot)$ is also bounded (exercise 7.26 in Grigoryan's "Heat Kernel and Analysis on Manifolds"). So far, then, we know that $h(t,x, \cdot) \in L^\infty (M) \cap L^2(M) \cap L^1(M)$ for all $t,x$. This motivates the following question:

> are there other $p \ge 1$ such that $h(t,x, \cdot) \in L^p(M)$?

The only thing that I know is that in the exercises after section 7.4, Grigoryan claims that if $f \in L^q (M)$ then $\int _M h(t,x, \cdot) f \in L^q (M)$, for all $q \in [1, \infty]$ and that this formula defines a $1$-parameter semigroup (though he does not claim that this is a $C_0$-semigroup - is it?).

Comment: You have $\lVert h(t, x, \cdot)\rVert_p\le  \lVert h(t, x, \cdot)\rVert_1^\frac1p \lVert h(t, x, \cdot)\rVert_\infty^{1-\frac1p}$ ("log-convexity of $p$-norms"), so $h(t, x, \cdot)\in L^p$ for all $p\in[1, \infty]$.

Comment: Is this not the inequality underlying the Riesz-Thorin interpolation formula?

Comment: This is much more elementary, see my answer. You can see these inequalities as baby versions of Riesz--Thorin. However, here no complex analysis is involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g(\cdot):=h(t, x, \cdot)$. For all $p\ge 1$, you have the elementary inequality
$$
\left( \int_M |g|^p\right)^\frac1p=\left( \int_M|g||g|^{p-1}\right)^\frac1p \le \left(\int_M |g|\right)^\frac1p\lVert g\rVert_\infty^{1-\frac1p}, $$
from which you infer that $g\in L^p$, since the right-hand side is finite, as you observed.

(More generally you have $\lVert g\rVert_{p_\theta} \le \lVert g\rVert_{p_0}^\theta \lVert g\rVert_{p_1}^{1-\theta}$ for $\frac1{p_\theta}=\frac{\theta}{p_0}+\frac{1-\theta}{p_1}$; this is a consequence of the Jensen inequality called "log-convexity of the $L^p$ norms").